# Why is “ß” not used in Swiss German?

Tags: orthography, written-language, germanic-languages, german

What are some of the historical reasons why the orthographic symbol ß is not used in Swiss Standard German and “ss” is used instead?

Comment: spellling is arbitrary - typewriters even more so....

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It is because of the typewriter. A Swiss typewriter needs to support three languages: German, French, and Italian. Therefore on the Swiss typewriter, there was no ß key. It also has only lowercase umlauts ä, ö, and ü. A picture of a Swiss typewriter can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ#/media/File:QWERTZ_swiss.jpg).

The lack of that key has led to a subsequent deprecation of the ß overall.

Comment: Related: That's also why Swiss town names don't start with Umlauts and use Oe Ae Ue instead (e.g. Oerlikon).

Comment: This doesn't sound like a sufficient reasoning (in the logical sense) to me. One could also state "a swiss typewriter needs [...]. Therefore on the Swiss typewriter, there are ßäöü and ´`^°"

Comment: @SebastianMach back in the old days when typewriters where still mechanical, this wasn't that easy

Comment: @SebastianMach In the olden days, languages were far more beholden to practical considerations than they are now. And why wouldn't they be? This is how languages have always evolved: necessity as well as changing habits.

Comment: @Josef: It does not sound plausible to me that the magic upper limit of the number of types is reached exactly where regional characters come into play. A typewriter from the same epoch e.g. features (roughly) 77 keys: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b2/bd/57/b2bd57885e1da4a15aff7a56891e627f.jpg

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Of course. Note that I am not criticizing any facts. I am just criticizing the "reasoning" and explanation of this answer.

Comment: @SebastianMach I understand. I am just criticising your criticising ;)

Comment: @SebastianMach The swiss typewriter linked to in the answer actually has more possible strokes than the one in your comment. Yours has 76 keys resulting in a stroke but no shift (hence the need to separate keys for upper and lower case), the answer's has 46 keys resulting in a stroke, but has a shift keys, which results in 92 possible strokes. And that's still not enough. It's weird, though, they they chose to use separate keys for ä, ö and ü instead of the dead key approach of just having ¨ (like they have ^ and `). Probably due to the higher frequency of those letters.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. German typewriters did not have ß either until the 1930s. See this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Typewriter_Adler_No._7_(1).jpg

Comment: It sounds kind of plausible, but do you have any evidence for this claim?

Comment: @jcaron: Yes. The point is that jknappen states _because of multi-language-support, it's hard to support ß_, which is not even a logical argument. The pure _number of keys_ can't be reason enough; to support that, I added that no-shift-keyboard to the discussion, which has more _physical_ keys.

Comment: I hereby claim this: The typewriter has no _ß_ because there's no _ß_ in Swiss. Now, whose claim-without-evidence is more plausible and more true, and why? (don't get me wrong - I am just hopelessly trying to tickle some logic- or evident-based reasoning out of jknappen, which, as my guts tell me, won't happen)

Comment: @fdb Despite being german-made, I'm not sure that typewriter was for the german market. The plaque just above the keyboard mentions Italy. The keyboard includes keys for letters that are predominantly french (é, ç). Maybe it was a Swiss version already?

Comment: @fdb [this version](https://typewriterdatabase.com/1911-adler-7.5104.typewriter) (from 1911) includes ß (visible on the M key, and on the typewritten example text).

Answer (score 32):

The Swiss government has an [explanation](https://www.bk.admin.ch/dam/bk/de/dokumente/sprachdienste/sprachdienst_de/rechtschreibleitfaden-2017.pdf.download.pdf/rechtschreibleitfaden-2017.pdf) on p. 18. One contributing factor is typography, namely the rise of use of the Antiqua font, which was claimed to not include ß. I have no evaluation of the truthiness of that claim, for the relevant historical period, i.e. prior to 1901. It is certainly the case that its shape in Antique was not uniform.

The [rules for using the letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) have been complicated and much of the 1996 [German spelling reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography_reform_of_1996) was about rules for *s*. As to why Switzerland was earlier and more radical in eliminating ß, this may be a cultural matter. Pairs like Flosse (fin), Floße (rafts), Buße (penance), Busse (buses) are rare and contextually not likely to lead to confusion.
One predicts that Masse (mass), Maße (dimensions) might still be distinguished with ss/ß.

Comment: "more radical in eliminating ß" - this seems to imply the changes of the 1996 spelling reform had the intention of eliminating ß, which is not quite the case.

Comment: Though it does give confusion with "Alkohol in Massen", which without the ess-tset to disambiguate can mean either "alcohol in moderation" or "alcohol en masse" ;)

Comment: @Muzer I think many people would prefer to parse it as "alcohol in 1 liter glass vessels like the ones used at Oktoberfest". You know, motivated reasoning and all that.

Comment: @Muzer you know the story of that health&safety campaign: “Alkohol – weniger ist besser!” Well, this wasn't considered strong enought, so they changed it: “Alkohol – nichts ist besser!”

Comment: I feel personally, that if a pair of homophones are not distinguished phonetically, then there isn't any need to distinguish them orthographically. The odds of one of the words of the pair occurring written down without context is low, and making the spelling unphonetic, or just plain confusing just to distinguish between them when written down feels awfully unnecessary and annoying (*cough cough japanese and chinese*).

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM: Pairs of words spelled with ß vs ss in German are not homophones: they differ in vowel length.

Comment: @brasstacks excuse my ignorance.